# Indoor Robot with No absolute starting yaw

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our indoor wheeled robot with wheel encoders has an IMU **without** magnetometers. At startup in a random orientation the yaw output is 0. We are able to follow a wall and cross into another room where an internal GPS is set up to determine X, Y and yaw with respect to global map frame of the room. We are using `robot_localization` for fusion, but are unsure how to switch to the room map without causing a discontinuity in the localization and therefore in the motion. Is it possible to go from map1 --> odom  to map2 --> odom ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283900/indoor-robot-with-no-absolute-starting-yaw/) by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No `tf` frame can have two parents. This sounds like a pretty straightforward two-tier setup. In your first EKF (*odom*->*base_link* transform), fuse wheel encoders and IMU. In the second (*map*->*odom* transform), fuse wheel encoders, IMU, and GPS data. You will experience a discontinuity in the map frame, but that's fine (it's the reason for having *map* and *odom* frames).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2